# jQuery cycle only current div

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/KTHWd/

so basically all divs has same class and i want to cycle only current div when i hover on it, currently cycles all divs when i hover.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'none',
        speed:    100,
        timeout:  100            
    });

    $('.slideshow').cycle('stop');
});


$(".slideshow").hover(
    function () {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.slideshow').cycle({
                fx: 'none',
                speed:    100,
                timeout:  100            
            });
        });
    },

    function () {
        $('.slideshow').cycle('stop');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the hover event, set the slideshow only on $(this). See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KTHWd/1/)

Comment: Additionally he can remove the ready that is inside the hover.